# Are there newer routing algorithms (than Dijkstra, A*) in GIS databases?

Tags: algorithm, routing, spatial-database, optimization

There are works like [Reach for A*](http://www.avglab.com/andrew/pub/alenex06.pdf) from Microsoft researchers and [Highway Hierarchies](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/source/contraction-hierarchies-20090221.tgz) by Sanders and Schtolz (if I spell the name correctly) from [Karlsruhe Uni](https://algo2.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/english/index.php). Both of them reduce the calculations order a lot, and speed up thousand times on large graphs (see the results in the linked documents). The latter work led to [Open Source Routing Machine](http://project-osrm.org/), which unfortunatly isn't popular enough and not adapted (I couldn't compile it although tried hard).

At the same time, the dbs that I tried, Spatialite and PgRouting, according to their docs, offer just Dijkstra and [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) algorithms. I've not even seen bi-directional search mentioned, which saves calculation time twice in my experience.

Are there better algorithms for databases or other applications?

Comment: Have you posted your question to the pgRouting users or developers email lists?  You might get a better response directly from that community.  

User list: (http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/pgrouting-users)
Developer list: (http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/pgrouting-dev)

Comment: +1 Great question.  I wonder what algorithm google uses for _Get Directions_ .  Related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147353/google-map-get-direction-search-algorithm).

Comment: Since Google supported Karlsruhe team (https://algo2.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/english/index.php) I suppose they use their software, which is essentially Open Source Routing Machine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The truth is that most people use a custom variation of the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) algorithm. You will see this across the most of the "big guys"(I can't say who they are in a public forum, but I can tell you that you probably use one of them - guaranteed), where the modification of the heuristics is very dependent on the datasets that they use.

You mentioned [pgrouting](http://www.pgrouting.org/) already, which I would consider a "traditional" option. It is good for doing simple routing algorithms and for most problems. It is also easy to use and uses a traditional database at its backend.

Nevertheless, it really depends on the scale and type of problem you are trying to solve and routing is a *graph* problem.

Once again, the "big guys" usually have a lot of data that is associated with their graph (for example, traffic data, bus routes, walking paths) that affect the routing algorithm. These are known as multi-modal trip planners (where you also have a choice of planning "modes" - no bike paths - only public transit - that kind of thing). You can think how trip planning also becomes a time sensitive issue (i.e if you walk *back* a few edges back, you will be able to catch the subway that takes you to your destination *forward* much faster than if you just tried to navigate the edges forward using the lowest cost).

The "big guys" don't store their data in a traditional database per se, they use pre-computed graphs (welcome hadoop/mapreduce clusters!). As you can imagine, these graphs become really big, so knowing how to connect the edges of adjacent graphs can be a challenge.

Anyway, I would recommend you look at some multi-modal routing graph projects:

[Graphserver](http://graphserver.github.com/graphserver/) comes to mind. Not a lot of documentation but a lot of pure coding awesomeness (AFAIK, I believe MapQuest uses a variation of this project for some of their routing products).

Another option would be the [OpenTripPlanner](http://opentripplanner.org/) which has a lot of smart people behind it (including people from graphserver).

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if it is *newer* but pgRouting has a [Shooting-Star algorithm](http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/foss4g2008/ch09.html):

> Shooting-Star algorithm is the latest
>   of pgRouting shortest path algorithms.
>   Its speciality is that it routes from
>   link to link, not from vertex to
>   vertex as Dijkstra and A-Star
>   algorithms do. This makes it possible
>   to define relations between links for
>   example, and it solves some other
>   vertex-based algorithm issues like
>   “parallel links”, which have same
>   source and target but different costs.

ESRI's Network Analyst extension uses the [hierarchical approach](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Algorithms_used_by_Network_Analyst/004700000053000000/) you mentioned to limit solving times:

> Finding the exact shortest path on a
>   nationwide network dataset is
>   time-consuming due to the large number
>   of edges that need to be searched. To
>   improve performance, network datasets
>   can model the natural hierarchy in a
>   transportation system where driving on
>   an interstate highway is preferable to
>   driving on local roads. Once a
>   hierarchical network has been created,
>   a modification of the bidirectional
>   Dijkstra is used to compute a route
>   between an origin and a destination.

There is a very detailed [white paper](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/whitepapers/view/productid/87/metaid/1054?ESRISessionID=8q162mcyrp4tvv_5A7bkwolWcutbjR8cMZI4EsceBCMUQz84YK9X1WOO1ohKtJ7Hh3PBRmLPhIsn) with examples on this approach at the ESRI site - however it requires you to log in to download (Hierarchical Routes In ArcGIS Network Analyst White Paper).

Answer (score 11):

*Contraction* Hierarchy is a very fast algorithm:

- http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/1087.php

This algorithm is RAM friendly while executing a query (to hold a contracted graph some more RAM is necessary as well as massive preprocessing)

There are some other algorithms - including the ones that solve public transit routing:

- http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/members/thomas_pajor/publications

Microsoft is also doing some research:

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dadellin/

(well, Daniel Delling is from Karlsruhe too)

You can get a nice introduction and overview of available algorithms:

- http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/teaching/sommer2012/routenplanung/index

Warning: german (!) lectures. but at least the headers can help you to get more information (ALT, Arc-Flags, CHASE, ...) or the appended literature!

**update**

[GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper) now implements contraction hierarchies and also other algorithms, you can also try out the [demo](http://graphhopper.com/maps/).